# after updating chrome(35.0.1916.114 m), webkitNotifications does not work

Tags: google-chrome, webkit-notifications

my chrome browser's version is 35.0.1916.114 m.

after updating, window.webkitNotifications object is undefined....

why? please help me

Comment: What version did you have before? The WebKit version has probably been made obsolete.

Comment: Who voted to close this question as "general computing hardware and software"? It's a Chrome API question.

Answer (score 1):

The chrome/webkit api is replaced:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/8vqyfHa8_dw

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications